# How to test/verify database table loaded by jdbc against data file?

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am creating table using schema file and loading table from data file through jdbc. I am doing batch upload using `PreparedStatement` and `executeBatch`. Data file contents look like the following structure:

```
key  time   rowid  stream
X    11:40   1      A
Y    3:30    2      B
```

Now I am able to load successfully table in database. But I would like to test/verify that same table loaded into database against this same data file. how do I do it? How do compare table in database with data file? I am new to JDBC. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read a jdbc tutorial. Do a `SELECT` on your table and compare your file with the `ResultSet` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Loki said, you can use a tool like DBUnit. Another option is to make a rudimentary integration test whereby your test generates a dump file of your table and compares this dump with the original "good" file.

Answer (score 0):

You need DBunit . Check more details here : http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html

DB unit helps you to write test cases against data from database.